# Specified return fields in contact get do not get returned

Tags: api

If I do a api3 contact 'get' with no return fields specified, it obvs returns all the fields including address fields.

What I want to do is only retrieve certain fields for my needs, just to reduce overhead.

If  I specify to return only 'state_province_name' or 'geofield1', they are not returned.

Is there a way to do this in a single call?

Answer (score 2):

If include 'state_province' in return param it should return you state_province_id, state_province_name and state_province.

For geofield1 you need to use 'geo_code_1'.

If you search for primary address in return field drop down under api explorer you should see the exact name for fields to retrieve for address.

```
$result = civicrm_api3('Contact', 'get', [
  'sequential' => 1,
  'return' => ["address_id", "city", "postal_code", "state_province", "geo_code_1", "country"],
  'state_province_name' => ['IS NOT NULL' => 1],
]);
```

Comment: I also realised is quicker to use the address entity and do a join to the contact data.